# Automatic operation of the algorithm Watershed in OpenCV

Tags: opencv

fellow programmers, recently wanted to play with the algorithm Watershed in OpenCV, but faced with the fact that the network is no example of markers that puts the user, and the system automatically detects the boundaries. This code calls the function itself, but how to determine the position of the markers, or they are already embedded in the function Watershed?

```
 cv2.watershed(img,markers)
```

Comment: [This](https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_watershed/py_watershed.html) tutorial might help you understand the process